# Woo Shop Page Code using on different page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a home page and shop page. I don't want to set my home page to shop page.

Home page is full of custom content and widgets, and right before this content I would like to have list of products with same **pagination** as on shop page.

This means I could not use shortcodes to display products as default shortcodes do not support pagination.

Have gone through all the docs and tried possible ways. But it always breaks something.

Any advice will appreciated.

Thx.

P.S. While you reading this I'm still trying to find solution, so I might post something soon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found awesome solution right [here](https://gist.github.com/klihelp/7810337).

I'm using shortcode [product_category per_page="4" category="category-slug"]

To make pagination alive, you need to activate this pagination.
Here is the exact code snippet that need to be pasted into the theme's functions.php:

```
if ( defined('WC_VERSION') ) {
// ---------------------- WooCommerce active -------------------

    /**
     * Set Pagination for shortcodes custom loop on single-pages.
     * @uses $woocommerce_loop;
     */
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'kli_wc_pre_get_posts_query' ); 
    function kli_wc_pre_get_posts_query( $query ) {
        global $woocommerce_loop;

        // Get paged from main query only
        // ! frontpage missing the post_type
        if ( is_main_query() && ( $query->query['post_type'] == 'product' ) || ! isset( $query->query['post_type'] ) ){

          if ( isset($query->query['paged']) ){
            $woocommerce_loop['paged'] = $query->query['paged'];
          }
        }

        if ( ! $query->is_post_type_archive || $query->query['post_type'] !== 'product' ){
            return;
        }

        $query->is_paged = true;
        $query->query['paged'] = $woocommerce_loop['paged'];
        $query->query_vars['paged'] = $woocommerce_loop['paged'];
    }

    /** Prepare Pagination data for shortcodes on pages
     * @uses $woocommerce_loop;
     */
    add_action( 'loop_end', 'kli_query_loop_end' ); 
    function kli_query_loop_end( $query ) {

        if ( ! $query->is_post_type_archive || $query->query['post_type'] !== 'product' ){
            return;
        }

        // Cache data for pagination
        global $woocommerce_loop;
        $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['paged'] = $woocommerce_loop['paged'];
        $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['found_posts'] = $query->found_posts;
        $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['max_num_pages'] = $query->max_num_pages;
        $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['post_count'] = $query->post_count;
        $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['current_post'] = $query->current_post;
    }
    /**
     * Pagination for shortcodes on single-pages 
     * @uses $woocommerce_loop;
     */
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_template_part', 'kli_wc_shortcode_pagination' ); 
    function kli_wc_shortcode_pagination( $template_name ) {
        if ( ! ( $template_name === 'loop/loop-end.php' && is_page() ) ){
            return;
        }
        global $wp_query, $woocommerce_loop;
        if ( ! isset( $woocommerce_loop['pagination'] ) ){
            return;
        }
        $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['paged'];
        $wp_query->query['paged'] = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['paged'];
        $wp_query->max_num_pages = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['max_num_pages'];
        $wp_query->found_posts = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['found_posts'];
        $wp_query->post_count = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['post_count'];
        $wp_query->current_post = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['current_post'];

        // Custom pagination function or default woocommerce_pagination()
        kli_woocommerce_pagination();
    }   
    /**
     * Custom pagination for WooCommerce instead the default woocommerce_pagination()
     * @uses plugin Prime Strategy Page Navi, but added is_singular() on #line16
     */
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10);
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'kli_woocommerce_pagination', 10);
    function kli_woocommerce_pagination() {
        woocommerce_pagination(); 
    }
}// END WOOCOMMERCE
```

Nice way to go for this try. The next thing is to make pagination ajax based without page reloading...